# Como publicar um projeto com Base de Dados

Tags: visual-basic-6, visual-studio-2010

Boa tarde!

Hoje finalmente terminei o meu projeto e tenho que criar um executável. Neste momento estou a utilizar o Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express e de facto eu depois do publish consigo utilizar tudo normalmente. Para testar a ver se estava tudo correto, enviei para o meu colega de projeto, o documento em .rar e dá-lhe este erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se for possivel ajudar, ficaria agradecido. Obrigado!

Supostamente a minha base de dados deveria de aparecer aqui e isso não acontece 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pergunte à ele se neste caminho (`F:\MIGGS\...`)  existe o banco de dados (`LoginDB.mdf`) que é o banco de dados!

Comment: Esse caminho é do meu computador

Comment: Mas sim nesse caminho a base de dados está lá

Answer (score 0):

Faltou enviar para o seu amigo o arquivo `.mdf` que está escondido na solução.

Verifique nos seus diretórios de projeto o arquivo `.mdf` e junte ao arquivo `.rar`, preferencialmente no diretório indicado na mensagem.

Comment: Não consigo perceber. Que solução?

Comment: O seu projeto. Dentro dele tem um arquivo `.mdf`.

Comment: Sim, tem em baixo da pasta Bin, My Project,

Comment: Resources e obj